# Wrap panels and item collections

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection defined as

```
 public class BraiderList : ObservableCollection <Braider>
```

with the objects defines as

```
public class Braider : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

The XAML code for displaying the data is shown below. As far as it goes, everything works correctly but I'd like to change how the items in my collection are displayed. I'd like to have each item in my collection be a separate item in a wrap panel instead of them all being part of one control. Is there any way to do this in XAML or do I need to write the code in C# instead?

```
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8" Margin="2,2" ClipToBounds="True" >
        <WrapPanel Name="WPanel1">
            <Border Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <ItemsControl Name="MyList">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="SPanel1">

                                <Image Source="{StaticResource BraiderImage}" Height ="75" Width="150" Visibility ="{Binding ShowIcon}"/>
                                <Label Content= "{Binding Name}" Visibility ="{Binding ShowName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Content= "{Binding ProductionCounter}" ContentStringFormat="Production Counter: {0:0.0}" Visibility ="{Binding ShowProductionCounter}" />
                                <Label Content= "{Binding LeadFront}" ContentStringFormat="Lead, Front Deck: {0:0.0}" Visibility ="{Binding ShowLeadFront}"/>
                                <Label Content= "{Binding LeadBack}" ContentStringFormat="Lead, Back Deck: {0:0.0}" Visibility ="{Binding ShowLeadBack}"/>
                                <Label Content= "{Binding Address}" ContentStringFormat="IP Address: {0}" Visibility ="{Binding ShowIP}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML seems wrong.

What you're looking for is to set the `WrapPanel` as the [`ItemsPanel`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/) of the `ItemsControl`, in such a way that the `ItemsControl` uses the `WrapPanel` to layout it's items rather than being inside the `WrapPanel` itself, like this:

```
<!-- No Need for a WrapPanel outside the ItemsControl, remove it -->
<Border>
    <ItemsControl Name="MyList">
        <!-- use a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanel for this ItemsControl -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <!-- Rest of your XAML here -->
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. One short note for the sake of completeness, you have to also wrap it in an <ItemsPanelTemplate> to run.

Comment: @FrankE Corrected that.